# Iteration in dictionary using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using python 3.8 and I have list

```
 { "A1":[{"id": 1,"name": "abc", "isdeleted":true},{"id":2,"name": "pqr", "isdeleted":false},{"id": 3,"name" : "xyz", "isdeleted":false}]}
```

I want to iterate in dictionary and get result like

```
X = [1,2,3]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*note also change your boolean values to big letter "T" or "F", True not true and False not false.

```
myDict = {"A1": [
                {"id": 1, "name": "abc", "isdeleted": True}, 
                {"id": 2, "name": "pqr", "isdeleted": False}, 
                {"id": 3, "name": "xyz", "isdeleted": False}
                ]
                }
x = []

for item in myDict["A1"]:
    x.append(item["id"])

print(x)
```

output `[1, 2, 3]`

or you can use the shorter way:

```
myDict = {"A1": [
                {"id": 1, "name": "abc", "isdeleted": True}, 
                {"id": 2, "name": "pqr", "isdeleted": False}, 
                {"id": 3, "name": "xyz", "isdeleted": False}
                ]
                }
x = [item['id'] for item in myDict['A1']]

print(x)
```

Comment: I have updated the question can you please help me out on that

Comment: I've updated my answer. If this helped you, it would be great if you mark my answer as useful. :)

Comment: Nice. If you would mark my answer as useful, that would be great.

Answer (score 4):

Why not `[i["id"] for i in X]`?

Answer (score 0):

We can a create a list of type dict like these, change the dict as below. After slice the list.

```
myDict = {"A1":[{"id": 1,"name": "abc", "isdeleted":true},{"id": 2,"name": "pqr", "isdeleted":false},{"id": 3,"name": "xyz", "isdeleted":false}]}

x=[]
for i in X["A1"]:
    x.append(X['id']) 
Print(x)
```

Comment: I have updated the question, can you please help me out with that

Comment: I have edited my answer according to your question. It may help you.